# How to pass element to javascript function and access the first child

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I am creating check-boxes in my ASP.NET code behind a file in C#. I am adding an attribute value before adding the control to the page, therefore ASP is adding the attribute to the span surrounding the check-box and the label for the text. It looks like this:

```
<span data-bind="visible: showCheckBox(this)">
   <input id="" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$SecondaryForm$ctl00" value="1">    
   <label for="">Outside Source</label>
</span>
```

I have a function called `showCheckBox()` written in Knockout.js. It determines if the target checkbox should be displayed, based on the value of the selected item in the drop down list immediately preceding it. For example, if the value of the selected item in the drop down list is 1, then the target checkbox with a corresponding value of 1 would be visible. That function looks like this:

```
function showCheckBox(span) {
   var value = span.firstChild.value;
   return value == reason();  
}
```

`reason()` is the view model variable that holds the value of the selected drop down list item.
No matter what I do, I cannot get the value of the check-box to be sent correctly. It is always undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I am slightly confused. Which exactly value you struggle with? `span.firstChild` is undefined? Or `span.firstChild.value`? And what exactly is `span`, a DOM object?

Comment: Maybe I am way off, but I am sending the span DOM element to the function using "this" keyword. I am then trying to extract the value of the check-box and return the result of the comparison of it and the reason() view model variable

Comment: I am not very familiar with knockout, but have you debugged this code? I am not entirely sure `span` is what you expect it is

Comment: are you able to illustrate the problem in a plnkr? try logging the passed in span var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while also, a coworked suggested this solution.

Instead of assigning the value of the check box as the ID that corresponds to the drop down list view model variable, he suggested I assign it in the data-bind attribute instead. In my C# code behind file, that looks like this

```
cb.Attributes.Add("data-bind", String.Format("visible: showCheckBox({0})", reasonDetails[i].ReasonForSendingNoticeID.ToString()));
```

Which looks like this when displayed in HTML

```
<span data-bind="visible: showCheckBox(1)" style="display: none;">
<input id="" type="checkbox" 
name="ctl00$MainContent$SecondaryForm$ctl00" value="Outside Source">
<label for="" style="display: inline;">Outside Source</label>
</span>
```

Then I changed the function as follows

```
function showCheckBox(id) {
    return id == reason();
}
```

Doing it like so allowed us to directly pass the value into the function without having to pass the element or its child.

Thank you for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The first child in this HTML is actually a `textNode`, which `firstChild` will return if that is what is found. These are the actual characters it is returning: `"↵  "` (A return and a space).

You can use the [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) property instead:

```
function showCheckBox(span) {
    var value = span.firstElementChild.value;
    return value == reason();  
}
```

Also, don't forget to check the support tables for `firstElementChild`.

Comment: In the console it still said value was undefined. After thinking on it for a few hours, my coworker suggested a solution that worked for me. I posted it below if you would care to see. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Hm, that's really strange as it is working for me. Glad you figured out a solution though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is hidden, and it's because you're for a large part *not using KnockoutJS* at all. You should check the docs for [the KnockoutJS `checked` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).

There should very likely be *no reason to check the DOM inside view models, not even those handling visibility*. Instead, use the *view model*. You haven't quite posted a complete minimal repro, but here's what it should more or less look like:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.reasons = [{id: 1, txt: "Main reason"}, {id: 2, txt: "Other reason"}];
  self.reason = ko.observable(self.reasons[0]);
  
  self.showCheckBox = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.reason().id === 1;
  });
  
  self.hasOutsideSource = ko.observable(false);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
pre { font-family: consolas; background: smoke; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: reasons, value: reason, optionsText: 'txt'"></select>

<span data-bind="visible: showCheckBox">
  <label> 
    <input data-bind="checked: hasOutsideSource" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$SecondaryForm$ctl00" value="1">    
     Outside Source
  </label>
</span>

<hr>
This would be sent to your server / debug info:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

If you can't take the above approach, I strongly recommend considering skipping the use of KnockoutJS, because it'll probably cause you more trouble than it'll help you if you do to much DOM manipulation on your own.